# Como remover Markers um a um(javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, marker

Tenho o seguinte código para adicionar os meus markers:

```js
 function setParking(map)
{
   var pointA = { lat: -16.113700, lng: -45.825545 };
   var pointB = { lat: -15.284216, lng: -44.658747 };
   var poinC = { lat: -16.139567, lng: -43.236152 };
   
   setMap(map, pointA);
   setMap(map, pointB);
   setMap(map, poinC);
}

function setParkingMap(map, point)
        {
                var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Loja Cascais</h1>' +
                    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                    '<p><b>Morada:</b> Teste' +
                    '<p><b>Horário:</b> Teste 2 ' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<button onclick="">Obter indicações</button>'
                '</div>';

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString
                });

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: point,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Teste'
                });
                marker.addListener('click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
        }

function initMap() {
var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15, center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.696029, -9.424029)
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

setParking(map)
}

  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        initMap();
    });
```

O que pretendo agora é quando clico no checkbox chamar uma função que me apague um marker ou mais, experimentei o seguinte:

`poinC.setMap(null)`, mas não dá.

Alguem sabe como posso fazer isto?

Comment: Pode providenciar o evento e a função onde isso deveria ocorrer sff

Comment: <input id="chkOranTarif" type="checkbox" name="chkOranTarif" class="psform__checkbox" onchange="removeMap()"/>    function removeMap(){ poinC.setMap(null)}. Acho que não acrescenta grande coisa mas a ideia é esta

Comment: Faça debug: Se puser um alert dentro da função ele funciona? Não costuma ser problema mas ponha o ';' a seguir a `setMap(null);`

Comment: Talvez seja um erro na sintaxe nos pontos A e B você tem `pointA/pointB` e no C tem `poinC`

Comment: Na consola o erro que me dá é o seguinte:  poinC.setMap is not a function

Comment: Percebe bem inglês? Se sim pode dar uma olhadela aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286913/google-maps-setmap-is-not-a-function e aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099556/why-setmapnull-is-not-working-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: O problema é que não quero ter um array de pontos, quero ter tudo individualizado. pois conforme a checkbox selecionada pode aparecer um Marker ou não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já descobri o que estava mal, estava a apagar pontos e não markers, criei 
`markers= []`, sempre que adiciono um marker faço
`markers.push(marker);` 
e na função de apagar faço:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
  markers[i].setMap(map); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se puder uma sugestão para evitar o ciclo for pode fazer:

```
<input id="chkOranTarif" type="checkbox" name="chkOranTarif" class="psform__checkbox" onchange="removeMap(this)" data-marker="<MARKER A REMOVER>"/>
```

EX:

```
<input id="chkOranTarif" type="checkbox" name="chkOranTarif" class="psform__checkbox" onchange="removeMap(this);" data-marker="0"/>

...

function removeMap(checkbox) {
   var markerToDel = checkbox.data('marker'); // aqui vai ser o num 0
   markers[markerToDel].setMap(null); // apagar o primeiro, markers[0].setMap(null);
}
```

Comment: E assim apaga todos?

Comment: Só apaga o que você quer, se para cada checkbox tiver um marker associado... Se for para apagar todos então o ciclo for é o que recomendo

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mas neste caso tenho várias checkbox e a combinação das mesmas é que fazem mostrar uns markers e outros não por isso vou ter que usar o for mesmo. Obrigado pela dica